# Collection type: First input is being ignored

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am having troubles with the collection type. I can't make it save the first input.

here is my form:

```
 ->add('urls', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => UrlType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'label' => 'my label',
            'label_attr' => ['class' => '...'],
            'required' => false
        ])
```

I slightly adjusted my `collection_widget` and `url_widget`. My main concern is that the fist input in the collection has `id="form_urls" name="form[urls]"` as its attributes. And the following ones (I made them appear by clicking on the button +) has right attributes `id="form_urls_1" name="form[urls][1]"`, `id="form_urls_2" name="form[urls][2]"`.

All that results in inability to save the first input (it just ignores it). How can I solve the problem?

Comment: And it save the others ?

Comment: @KubiRoazhon yes

Comment: try to change the name of all of your inputs into `form[urls][]`

Comment: @KubiRoazhon edited: I did change it manually, but doing so I had to remove `{{ block('widget_attributes') }}` which generated it automatically. I also used id's which were generated by this widget attributes, so I dunno if this is a good idea. But it worked, after all...

Comment: So I had to manually set the name of the input + give it widget_attributes. Altogether: `<input type="email" name="form[urls][]" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} ...>`. I don't know if this a good solution, but it works. Thanks to @KubiRoazhon